# Swift and google noSql database

Tags: google-app-engine, swift, cloud

Is it possible to consume a noSql database from the google cloud datastore in swift (can be objective-c)?

If it is, can you point me out some literature ?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there's a library for interacting with this from Objc or Swift *yet*. However, there's plenty of documentation on the [JSON API here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) which you can easily build a Swift or Objc client around.